# What can a half-ripe jackfruit be used for?

Tags: fruit, culinary-uses, asian-cuisine, indian-cuisine

We got a (fresh) jackfruit that was not so ripe... somewhat bland, not very tender and not enjoyable.

My question is: What should I cook with it?

I cooked it like I would a green jackfruit, but since it is somewhat ripe I figure I should treat it differently? I've cooked with canned green jackfruit before, but never as in this situation. I was planning a curry for the boiled seeds. I have no idea what to do with this boiled, half-ripe fruit!

Comment: I rolled back the tag culinary-uses, because it *does* apply. In fact, there is some discussion on this site about whether to allow questions such as this one, and the culinary uses of uncommon ingredients is one of the exceptions under which they are allowed. See also http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/what-is-the-current-practice-on-how-to-use-or-what-do-with-questions.

Comment: Ingredients being "uncommon" depends on where you are from. In some areas, jackfruit is common. Also, it is not normally discarded nor used in non-culinary applications.

Comment: I am aware that jackfruit is not rare in certain cuisines. This is why I considered closing your question, as being outside of our culinary-uses guidelines. But you specified that it is half-ripe, and not suited to either the usual recipes for ripe ones, nor for the usual recipes for canned green ones. This is why I left it open under culinary uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can make chips and halwa from half-ripe/ripe jack fruit,its famous snack in Indian states
 Even though the process of making chips is time consuming,the taste is explainable First step is to open the raw fruit then chop off the middle stem and pull out the the jack fruit ,then deseed it and slice into thin slices

**Ingredients for chips**.

Jack fruit- 1 medium size

Oil- 1kg

Salt-to taste

**Method of preparation**

```
· Remove fleshy part of Jack fruit from the seeds and slice them into long strips.
· Deep fry in oil.
· Sprinkle some salt water in the oil
· Deep fry till it turns yellow and crisp
· When the chips are done keep the fried chips In an air tight container
```

For jackfruit halwa :

**Ingredients for Halwa**

Half Ripe jack fruit- 1 medium size

Jaggery-1 kg

Ghee-1 cup

Cardamom powder-1 tbs

Dried ginger powder-1 tsp

Sugar-2 tbs(for sprinkling on the top when Halwa is done.)

**Method of preparation**.

· Clean and deseed the jack fruit.
· Grind them coarsely using a mixer grinder
· Heat jaggery along with 1/2 cup water to form a syrup.Strain the syrup for impurities and keep aside
· Heat a thick bottomed vessel(usually uruli, but anything would do) add ¼ cup ghee, and the jack fruit paste along with the jaggery syrup and cook on medium heat , stirring continuously. Do not increase the heat,to prevent it from sticking to the vessel. Add 1 tsp of ghee,whenever it starts to stick probably in every 15 minutes. …(Use a long handled ladle with a flat end so that our hands will be safe from the hot splutters, when the pulp boils and bubbles over ). Continue the process,until it turns dark brown colored and starts to come from the edges ,Add cardamom powder and dry ginger powder and stir for some more time to get thick and tight Halwa.
Transfer the Halwa into a plate and mark with a knife to our desired shape. Sprinkle sugar over it and Allow it to cool naturally
After cooling take out the Halwa and keep it in an airtight container.

**Cook Time**

Prep time: 30 min

Cook time: 1 hour 30 min

Ready in: 2 hours

Yields: 2kg

Hope it helps.